# Object Oriented PHP Query (dabl ORM)

Tags: php, oop, orm

I'm trying to use DABL ORM and its object oriented query building with a join however the results are only coming back from the first table I specify, can anybody advise what I'm doing wrong.

https://manifestwebdesign.com/redmine/projects/dabl/wiki/Object_Oriented_Query_Building

```
$stu = new Students;
$q = new Query;
$q->addColumn(Students::ADNO);
$q->join(Students::SEN, SenStatus::ID);
$q->addColumn(SenStatus::STATUS);
$students = $stu->doSelect($q);
```

Results when var_dump'd only show columns from students table.

There is no issue with the database structure as the normal sql query:

```
SELECT adno, status FROM students LEFT JOIN sen_status ON students.adno = sen_status.id
```

Works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've not heard of that one. I'm all for new ORMs to come out, but the development activity on that doesn't look very busy. Would Propel be better, given that their About page says they are similar?

Comment: not really, have been using the none OOP version for over 2 years but wanted to try this as the application I've built works fine with the normal way however now looking at using the extra functionality of dabl if possible

Comment: I'm guessing here, but after the code you have, try something like `$students[0]->getRelatedItem()` (i.e. I don't know the syntax but that would be sensible). You may find that the join has been executed correctly, but that the hydration of the related objects does not happen until you call the appropriate method. See the code files, or use an autocompleting IDE to get method prompts.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried all the syntax alternatives?

like

```
$students = Students::doSelect($q) ?
```